# Generate empty time object with php

Tags: php, time

I want to set an empty date into the database. With the following code I defining an empty date object.

```
$date = new \DateTime('0000-00-00');
```

I would expect that this code would generate and time object where the [date] contains all zero's. But it generates the invalid time object below.

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

Could this be an server setting as it works on my dev server?

Comment: define your database field with proper date type and dont `allow null` (allow null as false instead not null) value. in this case db will automatically set your filed as `0000-00-00` in case of date only. and this is same for date and time data filed too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to generate a datetime object with all zero's in PHP, as ISO 8601 forbids you from doing that.

If you want to make the date/datetime field in the database table optional, you should use NULL as default value instead of using NOT NULL and setting 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

"Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00')."

Note the use of the word "invalid" here.